# how to pass images from one activity to another?

Tags: android-intent

i am trying below code to pass images from one activity to another.

```
        Bundle search_opt=new Bundle();
         search_opt.putByteArray("key1", image1);
        search_opt.putByteArray("key2", image2);
        search_opt.putByteArray("key3", image3);

        Intent view=new Intent(CameraOpen.this,insertion_db.class);
        view.putExtras(search_opt);
        startActivity(view);
```

But i m getting error on

```
        Bundle search_opt=new Bundle();
        error :Unreachable code
```

Comment: Can you post some more context? I think the Bundle search_opt=new Bundle(); looks correct, but it might be included in the wrong place within your code.

Comment: @AdrianGrigo i am writinig this in OnClick function

Comment: thanx...by calling above code through function it works...but tell me why it was'nt working before..when i was writing these code lines in OnClick function

Comment: Can you post the code that didn't work as well as the code that did work and then I can have a look for you? I think you must have had a switch statement or while or return or something before the code which stopped Java from ever being able to reach your code.

Comment: @AdrianGrigo :i tried below code b4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the code.

I put the code you had been using before into a new project, and (after adding some dummy variables and classes) it compiles fine without giving any unreachable code errors.

So I can only speculate as to what may have been the problem. If I move the case R.id.okImage statement down a few lines, this makes it impossible for the normal flow of program execution to reach the Bundle line and gives an unreachable code error message. I can also get a similar message by commenting out the case R.id.okImage line.

```
// From the switch statement, program execution continues at either
// 1a) the case statement R.id.ibTakePic
// 1b) the case statement R.id.okImage
// 2a) a default statement (if you have entered one)
// 2b) or otherwise at the line following the switch
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ibTakePic:  // 1a
        for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
        {
            i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
        }
        break;

        // Thus the program will never run this code as it is after the break from the
        // previous statement and before the case line below.
        // This is an example of unreachable code
        Bundle search_opt=new Bundle();
        search_opt.putByteArray("key1", image1);
        search_opt.putByteArray("key2", image2);
        search_opt.putByteArray("key3", image3);

    case R.id.okImage:  // 1b
        Intent view=new Intent();
        view.putExtras(search_opt);
        startActivity(view);
        break;
    }
    // 2b
}
```

Comment: i don't know wats the prob was.....i got errors sometimes...sometimes i got errors on "R"...and then it will become ok

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this before

> > @Override
> >         public void onClick(View v) {
>
> ```
>   switch (v.getId()){
> ```
>
> > ```
> >     case R.id.ibTakePic:
> >      for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
> >        {
> >         i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
> >         startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
> >        }
> >         break;
> >     case R.id.okImage:
> >         Bundle search_opt=new Bundle();
> >        search_opt.putByteArray("key1", image1);
> >        search_opt.putByteArray("key2", image2);
> >        search_opt.putByteArray("key3", image3);
> >
> >        Intent view=new Intent(CameraOpen.this,insertion_db.class);
> >        view.putExtras(search_opt);
> >        startActivity(view);
> >
> >         break;
> >     }
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > @Override          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
> >
> > > ```
> > >   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> > >
> > >   if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==1 ){       
> > >                     Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
> > >                     bmp1=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> > >       iv1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
> > >                     byte[] image1 =Utilities.getBytes(bmp1);
> > >                     counter++;  
> > >              }
> > >
> > >   else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==2){
> > >                    Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
> > >                    bmp2=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> > >          iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
> > >                    byte[] image2 =Utilities.getBytes(bmp2);
> > >                    counter++;
> > >   }
> > >             else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==3){
> > >                   Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
> > >                   bmp3=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> > >         iv3.setImageBitmap(bmp3);
> > >                   byte[] image3 = Utilities.getBytes(bmp3);
> > >               } } }
> > > ```

Answer (score 0):

Now by doing this it works

> > ```
> >     case R.id.okImage:
> >         startother();
> >         break;
> >     }
> > }
> >
> >
> > private void startother() {         
> >
> >     Intent view=new Intent(CameraOpen.this,insertion_db.class);
> >     view.putExtras(search_opt);
> >     startActivity(view);    
> >    }
> >
> >
> > @Override
> > ```
> >
> > protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
> >     {
> >             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> >
> > ```
> >     if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==1 ){
> >                     Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
> >                     bmp1=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> >         iv1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
> >                     byte[] image1 =Utilities.getBytes(bmp1);                       
> >                     search_opt.putByteArray("key1", image1);
> >         counter++; 
> >              }
> >
> >     else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==2){
> >                     Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
> >                     bmp2=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> >         iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
> >                     byte[] image2 =Utilities.getBytes(bmp2);               
> >                     search_opt.putByteArray("key2", image2);
> >         counter++;
> >     }       
> >            else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && counter==3){  
> >                 Bundle extras=data.getExtras(); 
> >                 bmp3=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
> >             iv3.setImageBitmap(bmp3);   
> >                 byte[] image3 =Utilities.getBytes(bmp3);
> >         search_opt.putByteArray("key3", image3); }
> > ```
> >
> > }
> >     }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the image, you could save the image to the disk and pass the path/filename as a string to the other activity.

Comment: You could save those images in directory and put those filenames in database. the database would a lot lighter this way.

Comment: i m saving images in sql server.i m using sqlserver as db

Answer (score 0):

Easy method to pass a image from one intent to another.
On first `activity.java`:

```java
intent.putExtra("resId", R.drawable.image);                                 
startActivity(intent);                                                         
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();                                       
if (bundle != null) {                                                          
    int resId = bundle.getInt("resId");                                        
    imageView.setImageResource(resId);                                         
}
```